# Garbage collection in Android 3.2

Tags: android, memory

I have an Android application is handling the device camera. In the code an onPreviewFrame function loops forever and creates a new instance of YuvImage in every signle loop. Finally in the loop the instance is set to null, and so the system garbage collector can release allocated memory.

This works perfectly in Android 4.1, but in 3.2 it doesn't. In Android 3.2 os this application allocates more and more memory and finally runs out of memory.

What's wrong?

```
oPreview.oCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer( new Camera.PreviewCallback() 
{
   public synchronized void onPreviewFrame( byte[] bData, Camera oCamera)
   {
      ...
      YuvImage oYuv_image = new YuvImage( bData, iFormat, iW, iH, null);
      ...
      oYuv_image = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to set it to `null` since it's a local instance. Can you please show the whole loop?

Comment: If you solved the problem it is recommended you post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Plugin for Eclipse called "Memory Analizer". 
It can show you where exactly the memory "leak" is and what is filling your app till it runs out of memory.

Here is a tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html

I used it in the past and the plugin helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. A great plugin. Problem solved now.

Comment: You're welcome. Would be nice if mark the answer as the right answer. =)